# Unbound breaking points with Chrome JS Debugger on VS Code?

Tags: javascript, html, debugging, visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger

I just want to debug simple javascript embedded in an index.html but the debugger on VSCode 1.60.0 don't stop at the breaking points because they are unbound. I tried it with "[Deprecated] Debugger for Chrome" and the already activated "JavaScript Debugger v1.60.1" plugin.

launch.json

```
"configurations": [
{
     "type": "pwa-chrome",
     "request": "launch",
     "name": "JS Client Debugger",
     "url": "http://localhost:80/test1/index.html",
     "trace": true
}
//OR
{
     "type": "chrome",
     "request": "launch",
     "name": "Launch Chrome against localhost",
     "url": "http://localhost:80/test1/index.html",
     "webRoot": "${workspaceFolder}",
     "breakOnLoad": true,
     "sourceMaps": true,
     "sourceMapPathOverrides": {
     "*": "${webRoot}/*"
}
}
]
```

index.html

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en-us">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
  <title>Test</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="test"></div>
  <script type='text/javascript'>
   ->Breakingpoint  var statusElement = document.getElementById('test');  
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

What I'm doing wrong here?
Thanks...